# Random Image in <Div> from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm trying random image to show in div with help of JavaScript and CSS got script on internet somewhere, trying to make gallery with this, each of 2 image set from which 1 will be shown. don't know if it's because of image address or code

images are in website `dir/images/a1.jpg, When I open file in browser, images do't show

```js
$(function() {
  var url = "/images",
    imgArray = [url + "images/a1.jpg",
      url + "images/a2.jpg",
      url + "images/a3.jpg",
      url + "images/a4.jpg",
      url + "images/a5.jpg",
      url + "images/a6.jpg"
    ],
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length)),
    baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";

  $(".slider").css('background-image', baseUrl);
})
$(function() {
  var url = "/images/",
    imgArray = [url + "/images/a7.jpg",
      url + "/images/a8.jpg",
      url + "/images/a9.jpg",
      url + "/images/a10.jpg",
      url + "/images/a11.jpg",
      url + "/images/a12.jpg"
    ],
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length)),
    baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";

  $(".slider2").css('background-image', baseUrl);
})
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.slider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

.slider2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider1">
</div>

<div class="slider2">
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you facing here?

Comment: `$(".slider1")` instead of `$(".slider")`

Comment: when i open index file in browser images doesn't show

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Comment: `url = "/images"` and then `url+"images/a1.jpg"`. Is this right (i.e. your image url really is `/imagesimages/a1.jpg` or is that a typo?

Comment: Probably because the resulting url is `/images/images/a7.jpg`.

Comment: if you're appending the `url` var to he array items you're looking in `/images//images/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two thing to be notice

- Location of the image
- referring to wrong class

```js
$(function() {
  var imgArray = ["/images/a1.jpg",
     "/images/a2.jpg",
     "/images/a3.jpg",
     "/images/a4.jpg",
     "/images/a5.jpg",
     "/images/a6.jpg"
    ],
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length)),
    baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";

  $(".slider1").css('background-image', baseUrl);
})
$(function() {
  var imgArray = ["/images/a7.jpg",
      "/images/a8.jpg",
      "/images/a9.jpg",
      "/images/a10.jpg",
      "/images/a11.jpg",
      "/images/a12.jpg"
    ],
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length)),
    baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";

  $(".slider2").css('background-image', baseUrl);
})
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.slider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

.slider2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider1">
</div>

<div class="slider2">
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have the variable

```
var url = "/images/"
```

And you have then

```
url+"/images/a7.jpg"
```

That mean your path is

```
/images/images/a7.jpg
```

Just remove the folder one time for example like this

```
 $(function() {
  var url = "/images/",
    imgArray = [url + "a1.jpg",
      url + "a2.jpg",
      url + "a3.jpg",
      url + "a4.jpg",
      url + "a5.jpg",
      url + "a6.jpg"
    ],
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length)),
    baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";

  $(".slider1").css('background-image', baseUrl);
})
$(function () {
    var url = "/images/",
        imgArray = [url+"a7.jpg",
                   url+"a8.jpg",
                   url+"a9.jpg",
                   url+"a10.jpg",
                   url+"a11.jpg",
                   url+"a12.jpg"],
        randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length)),
        baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";

    $(".slider2").css('background-image', baseUrl);
})();
```